# Unable to redirect after login in React app using AWS Cognito

Tags: reactjs, amazon-web-services, amazon-cognito

I'm learning React as I need to write an AWS app using Cognito. This series of videos is very helpful (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=R-3uXlTudSQ&list=PLDckhLrNepPR8y-9mDXsLutiwsLhreOk1&index=3&t=300s) but it doesn't explain how you redirect your app after you've logged in.

my App.js is this:

```
export default () => {
  return (
    <Account>
      <Status />
      <Signup />
      <Login />
      <ForgotPassword />
      <Settings />
    </Account>
  );
};
```

The Settings component will only appear for an authenticated user. However, once you've logged in it doesn't appear until you refresh the page. How do I get it to show the settings page without having to refresh the page?

The settings component is:

```
export default () => {
  return (
    <Account>
      <Status />
      <Signup />
      <Login />
      <ForgotPassword />
      <Settings />
      <SearchParms/>
    </Account>
  );
};
```

And the Accounts component is this:

```
import React, { createContext } from "react";
import { CognitoUser, AuthenticationDetails } from "amazon-cognito-identity-js";
import Pool from "../UserPool";

const AccountContext = createContext();

const Account = props => {
  const getSession = async () =>
    await new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      const user = Pool.getCurrentUser();
      if (user) {
        user.getSession(async (err, session) => {
          if (err) {
            reject();
          } else {
            const attributes = await new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
              user.getUserAttributes((err, attributes) => {
                if (err) {
                  reject(err);
                } else {
                  const results = {};

                  for (let attribute of attributes) {
                    const { Name, Value } = attribute;
                    results[Name] = Value;
                  }
                  resolve(results);
                }
              });
            });

            resolve({
              user,
              ...session,
              ...attributes
            });
          }
        });
      } else {
        reject();
      }
    });

  const authenticate = async (Username, Password) =>
    await new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      Username = "nick.wright@maintel.co.uk";
      Password = "C411m3di4**&";
      const user = new CognitoUser({ Username, Pool });
      //const authDetails = new AuthenticationDetails({ Username, Password });
      
      const authDetails = new AuthenticationDetails({ Username, Password });
      user.authenticateUser(authDetails, {
        onSuccess: data => {
          console.log("onSuccess:", data);
          resolve(data);
        },

        onFailure: err => {
          console.error("onFailure:", err);
          reject(err);
        },

        newPasswordRequired: data => {
          console.log("newPasswordRequired:", data);
          resolve(data);
        }
      });
    });

  const logout = () => {
    const user = Pool.getCurrentUser();
    if (user) {
      user.signOut();
    }
  };

  return (
    <AccountContext.Provider
      value={{
        authenticate,
        getSession,
        logout
      }}
    >
      {props.children}
    </AccountContext.Provider>
  );
};

export { Account, AccountContext };
```

In Settings I have

```
import React, { useState, useEffect, useContext } from "react";
import { AccountContext } from "./Accounts";
import ChangePassword from "./ChangePassword";
import ChangeEmail from "./ChangeEmail";

// eslint-disable-next-line import/no-anonymous-default-export
export default () => {
  const [loggedIn, setLoggedIn] = useState(false);

  const { getSession } = useContext(AccountContext);

  useEffect(() => {
    getSession().then(() => {
      setLoggedIn(true);
    }).catch((err) => console.log("Catch", err) )
  }, [getSession]);;


  return (
    <div>
      {loggedIn && (
        <>
          <h1>Settings</h1>

          <ChangePassword />
          <ChangeEmail />
        </>
      )}
    </div>
  );
};
```

and at this line:

```
const { getSession } = useContext(AccountContext);
```

I'm getting an "AccountContext is not defined" error.

I haven't been able to find any online examples that solve this issue. Is there a way of dynamically showing/hiding each element when the login button is clicked.

Answer (score 1):

In this case, there's no need to define `getSession`, `authenticate` and `logout` on the context. You can put those functions inside a `auth` folder and call them whenever you need wihout having to define them in the context. What you need to define in the context is whether the user is logged in or not, because that's the information that you want to share in your whole application. Regarding the `AccountContext is not defined`, I don't see any issues from what you have shared. https://codesandbox.io/s/adoring-sun-kz30yr?file=/src/Settings.js